# Compiler error: implicit declaration of function 'find_task_by_vpid'

Tags: c, linux, process, kernel

```
if(find_task_by_vpid(pid)) 
{
   myProcess = kmalloc(sizeof(find_task_by_vpid(pid)), GFP_KERNEL);
   myProcess = find_task_by_vpid(pid);
}
```

I've included `sched.h` where this method is declared, but am getting the following errors:

(on the first line) warning: `implicit declaration of function 'find_task_by_vpid'`

(on the last line) warning:`assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast`

Presumably the issues are related, but I can't figure out what the matter is.
Running Ubuntu (6.06.2) linux kernel version 2.6.15.51-server.

Comment: I don't see why they are related. And there's no way to reproduce the problem with such little information.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're including the wrong sched.h. My system has several sched headers but only /usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0-18/include/linux/sched.h contains the declaration of find_task_by-vpid(). I recommend you check your include paths.

Comment: And you could pass `-H` to `gcc` to find out which headers are actually included.